# Weird behaviour of cv::circle

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, kinect

I'm trying to draw a couple of circles with OpenCV 3 onto an image which is obtained from the Kinect v2 sensor.

There seems to be a strange bug with `cv::circle` or I don't understand how the function works. Let's look at some code:

```
if(kinectDataManager.IsColorStreamEnabled())
{
    cv::Mat colorFrameMat = kinectDataManager.GetFrame().GetColorFrame()  

    cv::imshow("Color", colorFrameMat)
}
```

This code works perfectly fine, and using the ImageWatch Visual Studio Plugin for inspecting OpenCV images, I can see that the `colorFrameMat` matrix is not corrupted.

Let's look at some more code:

```
if(kinectDataManager.IsColorStreamEnabled())
{
    cv::Mat colorFrameMat = kinectDataManager.GetFrame().GetColorFrame()  

    int radius = 2;
    int y = 1068;

    for (int x = 0; x < 1920; ++x)
    {
        cv::circle(colorFrameMat, cv::Point(x,y), radius, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), -1, CV_AA);
    }

    cv::imshow("Color", colorFrameMat)
}
```

After the loop execution has finished, the ImageWatch plugin reveals that the last rows of the image are missing. Strangely, the program still executes. However, for different values of `y`, the program crashes due to access violations, e.g. for `y = 1067`, the program crashes for `x = 1917`. For `y = 1069`, it crashes at `x = 988`.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be?

EDIT:
The ImageWatch plugin of course reveals that the last rows are missing, as circles are drawn at these positions from left to right, sorry for the mistake!!

EDIT2:
After storing one frame and reading it in, the `cv::circle` method with the identical code works fine:

```
cv::Mat test = cv::imread("test.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv::namedWindow("test", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
int radius = 10;
int y = 1067;

for (int x = 0; x < 1920; ++x)
{
    cv::circle(test, cv::Point(x, y), radius, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255, 255), -1, CV_AA);
}

cv::imshow("test", test);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Why don't you work in terms of `Mat.rows` or `Mat.cols` (or `Mat.size().width` / `Math.size().height`) ??

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to my question. I obtain width and height of the image frame using the Kinect SDK functions. Immediately before the `imshow` call, `Mat.rows` and `Mat.cols` are `1080` and `1920` respectively.

Comment: Because without any log, crash log, or constants, it's a little bit difficult to help

Comment: I can totally understand that, however, I don't know what kind of log I could provide. Prior to the `cv::circle` calls, the image looks totally fine. Somewhere during the loop, the last rows are lost...

Comment: The memory occupied by your image is fixed. If you assume a wrong image width or height, your assumed pixel line starts at a very wrong position. That's why your code crashes at different x coordinates. Take an image of 4 rows and 512 columns. Now if you ask for the 1st row will start at memory location 0, 2nd row will start at 512, and so on. But if you assume the image to have 1024 columns, you expect the 2nd row to start at position 1024 instead. If you now try to access your non-existent 1024 pixels of that row you'll end in the last position of the 4th row.

Comment: can you print `std::cout << colorFrameMat.cols << " x " << colorFrameMat.rows << std:.endl;` please?

Comment: This returns 1920x1080, as expected.

Comment: I see what you mean Micka. Strangely, if `x = 1068`, the blue circles are drawn at the expected positions. However, for values `x = 1067` and `x > 1068`, the program crashes.

Comment: Can you please provide a working code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kinect SDK provides only functionality to read a 4-channel image (i.e. RGBA), however, the `cv::circle` functions seems to crash in a strange way for these kind of images. By dropping the alpha channel with a call to `cvtImage`, I could resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say the image looks fine before the `cv::circle` call it is possible that `GetColorFrame()` returns data that changes while the loop is running.
Try:

- a `GetColorFrame().clone()` to see if this fixes the issue, or
- change the way `GetColorFrame` works.

Comment: That's a good idea! However, the problem still remains, even for the very first frame.